# How can the chaincode , nodejs components be generated from fabric-composer definintions?

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

Using the definitions created using fabric-composer, can one generate the chaincode and individual nodejs components i.e REST API and UI ? So that it can be later run without using fabric-composer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, then you can't. Hyperledger composer provides a runtime that resides inside of a Hyperledger fabric chaincode container that manages and executes the various artifacts that make up a business network definition. A business network definition is not generated into standalone chaincode.
The Rest Server that provides the rest API for a business network also relies on Hyperledger Composer APIs to interact with the runtime to be able to dynamically introspect the business network and provide access to that business network. The Rest Server provides the flexibility to create any type of UI you wish and doesn't have to be generated from the Yo generator provided by Hyperledger Composer.

Comment: Would composer create a separate chain code for each business network?